# How To Display Text And URLs For An Emails Hyperlinks in MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, phishing

Is there a way in outlook to change:

"Some random email text. Please go to this [Search Engine](https://google.com)"

to be displayed as :

"Some random email text. Please go to this [ Search Engine, https://google.com ]"

The displayed format for the solution is irrelevant. The main thing I want is that the url of the hyperlink shows up next to the hyperlinks descriptive text, instead of being nested/hidden inside.

Bonus: Same thing for any component of an e-mail pointing to an external server.

This is to improve my ability to spot phishing e-mails. I just fell for one generated by my companies IT security and I would like to improve my chances in the future.

Comment: Is this you adding a hyperlink in a new e-mail window? Or on e-mails that arrive into your inbox?

Comment: Arriving into my inbox.

Comment: It depends on how the sender edits this message. I'm afraid there is no build-in for this. You may try to find some code or script.